# How to obtain the order of multiple reponses?

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

I'm working on a survey dataset which contains a question with multiple responses. The data is not well cleaned for the order of responses depends on the order in which an interviewee chose the multiple options. So it's a so-called "many-to-many" multiple response (I borrow the term from [N.J. Cox and U. Kohler's tutorial](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/multiple-responses/#mention) on this topic). There are also several following complementary questions (like the year a certain event happened) which share the order of the first question. The basic data structure is like

```
 q1_1  q1_2  q1_3  q2_1  q2_2  q2_3
 1      3     .    1998  1999  .
 2      .     .    2000   .    .
 3      2     .    2001  1997  .
```

I can use code provided in [the tutorial cited](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/multiple-responses/#mention) to detect whether a certain value appears in `q1_*` and set a new dummy to 1 in this case. But how can I retain the order in which I encounter the certain value and use it in my analysis regarding `q2_*` in the loop?

```
forvalues i = 1/3 { 
       egen Q1_`i' = anymatch(q1_*), val(`i')  
  }
```

UPDATE

The current answer is brilliant, but it gives the general order, not the particular order in which a certain value occurs.

I may not have expressed my question clearly enough.

What I desire is to detect if a certain event (a option of the multiple responses represented by certain value like 3) happens. If it does happen, then set a new-created dummy, say `eventhappens`, to 1: so in my example, we shall set `eventhappens` to 1 for the first and third id.

If that's all my desire, then `anymatch()` suffices.

### However, I also need to retain the order in which the particular value 3 occurs, like 2 for first observation, to ease the analysis of the following questions. So for the first id, 1999 is the year when the certain event happened, not 1998. Then what should I do?

Update
Appologize for my former unclear description. The real data is like (I don't have the authority to post a picture of the real data in Stata browse window)

```
 id   ce101_s_1 ce101_s_2 ... ce101_s_13 ce102_s_1 ...... ce102_s_13
  1    1         2             13         1999   1998      2005 
  2    13        .              .         1999    2007       .
```

the ce101_s_* is a list of variable,they represent the options interviewee choose with regarding to question ce101 and their orders are the orders in which interviewee make the choice.Certain value(in the real data is chinese character with value labels)represents certain event had occured, for example 1 represents a villiage build its own hospital,13 represent a villiage has mobile signal and so on.Take id_1 for example, this village build a hospital (represented by 1) in 1999, build a preliminary school(represented by 2) in 1998 and so on, in fact , all event listed actually happened in id_1 village,but for id_2 only 2 and 13 event happens. The difficulty for me is to retain the order certain event happened in each villiage, take 13(mobile signal for instance),it occured in 2005 for id_1 village, because interviwee choose it at 13th order when answering question ce101, and the value of ce102_s_13 is 2005.But for id_2, interviewee choose it at the second order and the correponding value in ce102 is 2007.So if a want to create a dummy to represent if household live in certain villiage before certain event occur in this village, I need the order in ce102_s_*
         .

Comment: I've edited the question, but I still don't understand it. Clearly English is not your first language, and that's understood. I think it means that you need to give a worked example of data and desired results as well.

Comment: Hi , Nick, I update some more detail description and hope it's more clear this time, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, no clearer to me. You're expecting readers to decode a long verbal description. You should perhaps work with someone local with a better command of English/

Answer (score 0):

I am not especially clear what you want, but I suspect the one-word answer is `reshape`. This structure may make it easier for you to cross-relate responses.

```
. input id q1_1 q1_2 q1_3 q2_1 q2_2 q2_3

            id       q1_1       q1_2       q1_3       q2_1       q2_2       q2_3
  1. 1 1 3 . 1998 1999 .
  2. 2 2 . . 2000 . .
  3. 3 3 2 . 2001 1997 .
  4. end 

. reshape long q , i(id) j(Q) string 
(note: j = 1_1 1_2 1_3 2_1 2_2 2_3)

Data                               wide   ->   long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                        3   ->      18
Number of variables                   7   ->       3
j variable (6 values)                     ->   Q
xij variables:
                     q1_1 q1_2 ... q2_3   ->   q
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. rename q answer 

. split Q, parse(_) destring 
variables born as string: 
Q1  Q2
Q1 has all characters numeric; replaced as byte
Q2 has all characters numeric; replaced as byte

. rename Q1 question 

. rename Q2 order 

. list, sepby(id) 

     +--------------------------------------+
     | id     Q   answer   question   order |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   1_1        1          1       1 |
  2. |  1   1_2        3          1       2 |
  3. |  1   1_3        .          1       3 |
  4. |  1   2_1     1998          2       1 |
  5. |  1   2_2     1999          2       2 |
  6. |  1   2_3        .          2       3 |
     |--------------------------------------|
  7. |  2   1_1        2          1       1 |
  8. |  2   1_2        .          1       2 |
  9. |  2   1_3        .          1       3 |
 10. |  2   2_1     2000          2       1 |
 11. |  2   2_2        .          2       2 |
 12. |  2   2_3        .          2       3 |
     |--------------------------------------|
 13. |  3   1_1        3          1       1 |
 14. |  3   1_2        2          1       2 |
 15. |  3   1_3        .          1       3 |
 16. |  3   2_1     2001          2       1 |
 17. |  3   2_2     1997          2       2 |
 18. |  3   2_3        .          2       3 |
     +--------------------------------------+
```